# Delete Rows With Duplicate Data VBA

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am struggling with something that should be fairly straightforward, however, I have read at least 15 methods of doing this and cannot seem to get it to work.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
9:30:01 584.7
9:30:01 590
9:30:01 595
9:30:02 584.51
9:30:03 584.62
9:30:04 584.44
9:30:05 584.05
```

I only want one row per second, so of the first 3 rows, only one needs to stay.  I don't care if it is the first or the last, but the code I have been using keeps the last, 595 in this case.

The way I am doing it is with a for loop that clears the contents of the row that has the same time as the row below it.  I then sort the entire range.

I imagine there is a simpler way to simply delete the extra row from the get go.  However, when I use delete on the range, instead of clear, it won't remove all of the duplicate rows.

Here is what I want the data to look like:

```
9:30:01 595
9:30:02 584.51
9:30:03 584.62
9:30:04 584.44
9:30:05 584.05
```

I need this to happen for the entire sheet.  The time is Column B and the values are column C.

Here is the code I am using,

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.row - 1 + _
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For RowNum = 2 To LastRow
    If (Range("B" & RowNum) = Range("B" & RowNum + 1)) Then
    Range("B" & RowNum).EntireRow.Clear
    End If
Next RowNum

Range("A2:C" & LastRow).Sort key1:=Range("B2:B" & LastRow), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: If you loop bottom up then you can delete the row instantly.  Share your code and I'll help you out with that.

Comment: @PortlandRunner presents a great solution -- you could also potentially use the Range.RemoveDuplicates method for this (especially since your column structure is so well defined)... Here's an MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @Portland Runner I have added the code.  Your idea sounds very smart.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't loop. Use RemoveDuplicates. Way faster than any loop. One line of code.

```
Sub test()
    ActiveSheet.Range("B:C").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Edit: screenshots

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

Edit: Does not work in Excel 2011 for Mac (go figure).

Comment: This works only when the values in both columns are duplicates.  It doesn't delete the rows based only on the fact that 9:30:01 repeats.

Comment: @user2926358 I added some screenshots and amended the code to columns B and C instead of A and B

Comment: @teylyn Is it possible this doesn't work on a mac?  I am running Excel 2011 and no dice.  I ran it on my old PC and it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: You never mentioned Mac. I don't do Mac. Does the Data ribbon have a "Remove Duplicates" icon?

Comment: +1 for this solution too. But above comment is +1 for loops, they always work (even on Mac ;-))

Comment: It does.  And the code will work as long as the data in column B & C is repeated.  Kind of a shame since this is handled in just one line instead of a loop.

Comment: There seems to be [evidence](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/removeduplicates-macro/4f8a1b78-8848-4fa7-835f-4bfc7100e3b8) that the RemoveDuplicates method does not work on a mac.

Comment: This is not the first time a method fails to work in Excel 2011.  Thanks for finding that link.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub jzz()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row 'loop from row 1 to last row
    If Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then 'check if something is in the cell
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then 'check if cell is the same as next cell
            Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete 'if so; delete
            i = i - 1 'go back one row
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Another option is to go from the bottom up, like so:

```
Sub jzz()
Dim i As Long
For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row to 1 step -1'loop from last row to row 1
    If Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString Then 'check if something is in the cell
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then 'check if cell is the same as next cell
            Cells(i + 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete 'if so; delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

what you prefer to use if personal. Please consider the answer of teylyn as well, in this situation, it is very usable.

Comment: Thanks Jzz.  I had something like this and it only deletes the second item and leaves the 3rd.

Comment: sorry, my bad! Simply forgot one (crucial) line of code. I edited my answer. Trick is to go back one row once you delete the row below it, so that the value is evalueated again.

Comment: Jzz, this does it!  I could bet a lot of money that I tried this exact thing but it didn't work.  I will run this on the full data set tomorrow, hopefully it does it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh, I meant: `For i = Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row to 1 Step -1`  but then you have to change a few other things.

Comment: What is the correct step for the for loop to start from the bottom?  I can't seem to get it to work.  (VBA newbie, I know)